# Run duplicate IIS websites on same database

Tags: asp.net, sql, iis-7

I need some guidance in "best practice" for the following scenario:
I have a product that consists of an ASP.NET website and native smartphone apps for Android/iOS/WP that uses the website URL to call webservices.

We want to move the website from "www.ourdomain.com" to a sub domain like "www.login.ourdomain.com"

This means we're going to update the apps to point to the new URL which isn't a problem.
But as we all know, not all users update their apps instantly, so we want to have a "cross over period" where we run the website on both URLs.

It'll use the same database, but the ASP.NET site code will be altered a bit for the new sub domain site.

Is there any problems in doing this kind of cross over where 2 ASP.NET sites share the same database? (All id's in the db is auto incremented, or GUIDs)

Any help, suggestions or concerns is much appreciated.

Comment: Is it mobile apps(native) or mobile web(webkit) ? how it is using your website URL ? Web Service ? Please elaborate with details.

Comment: Hi Palak. 
The apps are native and therefore will require a version update. They communicate with the website through services.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem using different service URL for existing mobile apps(Old URL) & updated mobile apps(new URL) and website. I'll call it proxies.

The critical part is regression testing for mobile apps (old one & new one), with the latest change.

It would be great, if deployment fully incorporates the [Deployment Workflow](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/best-practices.html).